# Postman sending POST request with headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman

Using Postman I'm trying to test my Rails endpoint which is receiving a webhook request. Client attached one important information inside of payload headers (instructions are below):

```
The HMAC is created with the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm using your shared secret, then encoded in base64.

The HMAC is attached to the callback request in the X-NorthRow-Signature header.
```

To test my App I need to attach `X-NorthRow-Signature` inside of headers, like below:

[image: postman sample request]

But when I tried to get in to this headers via console it's `nil`

```
[2] pry(#<Webhooks::Northrow::ReceiveWebhookController>)> headers['X-NorthRow-Signature']
=> nil
```

What did I missed?

Comment: Protip - Instead of postman and pry use an integration test / request spec. It doesn't really take any longer to setup and gives you protection against future regressions... https://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#integration-testing

Comment: You also probally want `request.headers['X-NorthRow-Signature']`.